# sending broadcast intent from runnable

Tags: android, multithreading, broadcast

I want to send a broadcast from a new thread is start.

This is what i tried :

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //some other code for timing.
            // ..
            // ..
            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
            broadcastIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_ANSWER);
            this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }
    }).start();
```

But ofcourse i need context..this won't work.
How can i handle this.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I faced this problem too.

Here is my solution. The application in which you are implementing this must have an Activity.
So, in that Activity, make a static variable of itself and assign this to it.

ex:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    static MyActivity thisActivity = this;
    //rest of the code goes here
}
```

Now, in the thread, do this:

```
MyActivity.thisActivity.sendBroadcast(myintent);
```

hope, this answers your question!

Comment: Great idea for lots of bugs.

Comment: static activity is a step for memory leaks. Never do that.

Answer (score 3):

What I usually do, although quite hacky, is the following:

```
final Context mCtx = this;
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //some other code for timing.
        // ..
        // ..
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(mCtx, TargetClass.java);
        broadcastIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_ANSWER);
        this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
}).start();
```

Also, remember to include the target Java class in the Intent constructor.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Maybe this will make sense if Thread object is and instance of inner type of some Context's subclass? 
And there's no Thread.sendBroadcast method. Correct call is SomeActivityName.this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent).

Comment: sorry, I meant mCtx.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent).

Comment: Shouldn't it be

`Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(mCtx, TargetClass.class);` ?

Comment: I prefere
broadcastIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
broadcastIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);